# Obtaining Shipping Label through Contract Based API

Tags: acumatica

We currently have a scenario where we need to obtain a shipping label through the contract based API.

The scenario is we have a in-house tool where we create shipments, pack them, and try to confirm them. From here we need to obtain the shipping label (Either UPS or FedEx) to pass to the printer when the physical box goes down the line.

Currently, it doesn't attach them to the Shipment. Is there anyway to get to that label? According to the screen, it attaches it to the Packages line. But, I'm not seeing anywhere in the documentation on how to obtain this through code.

Comment: The pick pack ship module (part of Advanced Fulfillment) does all of that already; if you can get your hands on the source code or binaries you'll have a pretty complete example to look at, including spooling the label to the printer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SOAP interface of C-b API, you won't be able to do that. If you're using REST interface, that one should expose files attaches to both top-level item and details as well.